# Apache doesnt pop up htpasswd authentification

Tags: htpasswd

i've been having trouble in the last hour with htaccess file.

so what i want:
I have a folder which is located at http://myip.com/FOLDER and I want a simple authentification page via htaccess

So i did the following:

sudo htpasswd -c /home/daniel/.htpasswd daniel

Please do notice I'm a pure beginner and ive been following a guide. anyways I think with that command i store my htpasswd file in my home folder.

entered pw blablabla  etc, worked so far ^^.

I also created a ssl vhost:

my content:
File: /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl

```
<Location /myfolder>
AuthName "Private"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /home/daniel/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
</Location>

ServerName XYZX:443
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
```

default:

ServerName my adress
Redirect permanent / my adress

i get ssl and stuff but never the authentification page

apache2 restarted but I just never get the authentification page :(

would appreciate help

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have setup authentication in the `default-ssl` config file, so it will only work for the `https` site.

Regarding your comments, it seems that authentication for `https://myip.com/myfolder` works as expected.

Now, from my understanding, it seems you want the same behaviour for `http://myip.com/myfolder`.

If it is the case, i suggest to put the same `<Location>` config in file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

---

**EDIT**

Ok, so you should try to setup your `<location>` like this in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` :

```
<Location /myfolder>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AuthName "Private"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /home/daniel/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: sorry my bad, no its still NOT working

Comment: @tamani Edited, give it a try. If you have a 500 error place your `.htpasswd` file somewhere in your DocumentRoot directory

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the config in a file called `.htaccess` in the same folder you want to protect:

```
AuthName "Private"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /home/daniel/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show any enclosing `<Virtualhost>` directive in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl, but assuming there is one, that's an HTTPS-only host.  So does the authentication work at https://myip.com/myfolder ?